# Transpose of a matrix times another matrix times the first matrix ($A^T B A$)

Tags: matrices

Suppose there is matrix $A_{n\times m}$ and a symmetric matrix $B_{n \times n}$.
$A$ is a dense matrix with $n \gg m$, while $B$ is a very sparse but full rank matrix.
How do I compute $A^TBA$ in an efficient way?

Comment: LU-decomposition for sparse matrices. Notice to perform it only once for $A$, and transpose the result.

Comment: Note that you need only compute the entries above and including the leading diagonal. This is because $A^T B A$ is symmetric.

Comment: @max would the result of LU-decomposition be a dense matrices?

Comment: @Zestylemonzi it would only save half time, so that may be not too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that the best method from practical point of view is to calculate this product directly, i.e. calculate $D = BA$ and then $A^TD$.

Observe that $A^TD = \frac{1}{2}A^TD + \frac{1}{2}D^TA$. Expression $\frac{1}{2}A^TD + \frac{1}{2}D^TA$ can be computed efficiently in $m^2n$ floating point operations, since this operation is implemented in BLAS.

You can expect at most two times speedup over the direct approach. Take $B = I$. Then $A^TA$ must be formed and this cannot be done faster than in $m^2n$ floating point operations.

Comment: Why do we need to expand $A^TD$ into two terms to compute the value of it? Instead, can I compute $A^TD$ directly? Because $A^T$ is $m  \times n$ and $D$ is $n \times m$, the computation cost of $A^TD$ would still be $m^2n$.